# More particles as more area is painted

Tags: particles, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I want to populate trees along a road with Particles using weight painting to control the density.
My problem is that the particle system needs to know the final particles count - logically, I proceed from start to finish so with every newly painted areas, the tree density will more and more decrease as this number spreads to bigger area. This means I have to adjust and estimate the count every while, which is frustrating.
So is there any option how to tell the particle system to produce maximum (based on a weight paint) of 5 instances on area of i.e. 10x10 meters so the number of instances / particles will grow progressively as I paint? 
[image]
  [image]
[image]

Comment: If you use a Hair Particle System you can influence the Length instead of Density

Comment: @HenrikD I tested this now and it doesn't look like this changes particles count.

Comment: No but you dont need to adjust it. You just need to have all the particles you dont want to be invisible (scaled down to 0)

Comment: @HenrikD But this way milions of trees / particles will be hidden and only those in weight painted areas will be shown...?

Comment: yes! I dont know how much it affects the performance, you have to test it.

Comment: I am using Particle Instance Modifier and it seems it doesn't work :( The length parameter makes no change.

Answer (score 1):

As I haven't found any solution so far and this fixed-count workflow limits my daily work a lot, I have refreshed my "so-so programming skills" and I ended up with creating a Blender (2.79) addon which does this job for me.

With the addon, you set the **Density** parameter and the *Emmission Number* is adjusted accordingly:

[image]

I have placed the addon to Github and would be very happy is someone can test it and report any bugs.
https://github.com/jendabek/blender-particles-density

Comment: Ah, a great addon! Can surely use it if not recommend it to my friends! It has a similar function as the density in Graswald

Comment: Thanks, first I would like anyone to test it properly as I am not very skilled Python programmer and even it works for me flawlessly, there can be some bugs when i.e. using some different workflows...

Comment: OK, can I rewrite it to work with 2.8 or do you want to do that yourself? Asking since I want to get better at coding too

Comment: @DrachenSeele Of course, just create a branch or something like that :)